# How to print month numerically in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use `\printfield{month}.\printfield{year}`, which unfortunately prints the name of the month, rather than the number, despite me specifying `\usepackage[date=terse]{biblatex}`. I wonder if I use the wrong field with `\printfield`. Is there any list of all fields than can be used in the standard style?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
    @article{article,
        author={Luke, Saint},
        date={2022-12-24},
        title={Nativity of Christ},
        journal={Journal of Christian Stories}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[date=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{
    \list
    {\printfield{month}.\printfield{year}}%
    {}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
}{\endlist}{\item}
\begin{document}
    \notecite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: @KennethOdle That does not say much about customizing BibLaTeX styles. It only says which fields can be specified in the bib file, but not which fields can be printed with `\printfield` (which is not the same), and how they can be formatted.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a minimal document + bib item that shows the problem explicitly.

Comment: @AlanMunn Done, MWE added.

Comment: Generally `\printfield` should not be used directly to print dates or date components like month, year, day etc. Instead the date commands `\printdate` and friends should be used. The behaviour of `\printdate` and friends can be influenced by package options and ultimately by `.lbx` files. It's not quite clear to me what the use case is here, so I haven't attempted an answer, but if you are interested in an answer and share more details about what you're trying to do, I can see what I can do.

Comment: @moewe The goal is to have the bibliography printed like a list, where the item is the month and year. This is intended for a cv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `\DeclareFieldFormat{twodigits}{\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi}` and then using `\printfield[twodigits]{month}` works. I'm not sure if this is the ideal format to use here, but it works. With the `default` format, months before October will print as one digit.